# Is turning off antialiasing for HTML Canvas still not possible?

Tags: html, canvas, toggle, antialiasing

I am curious if anyone knows when this option might become available or if it ever will.

Comment: `ctx.mozImageSmoothingEnabled = false;` is available in Mozilla. Looks like it hasn't been implemented in webkit yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: Still not possible.

Here's part of [the working group's old discussion of the matter.](http://www.mail-archive.com/whatwg@lists.whatwg.org/msg10074.html)

For now, if you just want images to not be anti-aliased you can always draw them on whole pixels.

Comment: Thank you for this. I'll keep myself updated on these threads from now on :)

Comment: That old discussion ignores the possibility of wanting anti-aliasing turned off for reasons other than performance.  Sadly, people assume too much about what a programmers intentions will be.  What if you wanted to make an in-browser image viewer/editor to view/edit at the pixel level?  It can still be done, but you have to use horrendous workarounds.